# How to update my RSS feed when data changes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I am creating a RSS feed based on the data present in my database (SQL server 2008). I have done it in asp classic. 
My question is how will I be able to update my feed automatically when data in the database changes?

Comment: How your rss being consumed?

Comment: The RSS feeds are created through my code which is in asp classic. I am looping through the database when a user requests for the feed and generates it. But i want it to be updated automatically when data in the database change

Comment: How you send this rss to consumer of rss?

Comment: To whom you want to send the RSS

Comment: Basically the RSS feed is saved on the server the user is only given a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **generate RSS on demand**. It could be a url your consumer is using the get latest rss feed. You can generate the `RSS` when that url is being access and return the response in form of `RSS` with latest changes.

**Edit** based on comments.

You can use jQuery `ajax` to periodically call method on server that generates the `RSS` and you can also get `RSS` from this method. This [link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) expalins you to use jQuery and web method to send server call.

You can use javascript [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) to periodically send ajax call.

```
setInterval(function() {
  //your jQuery ajax code to check if you have updated RSS
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Yes I am generating RSS feeds on demand at present. But as per the client's requirement i need to update it automatically when data is changed.

Comment: Is your client using some url to get the feed?

Comment: yes. Actually the process is :There's a page with 3 dropdown options to generate an rss. when user selects any or none of these dropdowns and click generate it redirects to the page with the rss feed. RSS feeds are saved on the server when generate clicked and then redirect user to that RSS feed.

Comment: Is it possible for you to change the code of page requesting rss (having three drop downs and generate button)?

Comment: Yes i can change the code behind it but the interface is as per the client's requirement which we need to keep same